# Loading external SWF causes sandbox violation

Tags: flash, debugging, actionscript, cross-domain, actionscript-2

I am attempting to load an external SWF so that I can debug it. I do not control the SWF source however I do control the domain it is hosted on.

Here is my code:

```
import flash.system.Security;
Security.allowDomain("*");

var swf = ["http://rcnhca.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/assessment-quiz/quiz.swf", "quiz_content/data.swf"]

var loadListener:Object = new Object();
loadListener.onLoadComplete = function(target_mc:MovieClip, httpStatus:Number):Void {
    trace(">> loadListener.onLoadComplete()");
    trace(">> httpStatus: " + httpStatus);
}

var mcLoader:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
mcLoader.addListener(loadListener);

var mc:MovieClip = this.createEmptyMovieClip("mc", this.getNextHighestDepth());
mcLoader.loadClip(swf[0], mc);
```

However this is returning many of the following errors:

```
SecurityDomain 'http://rcnhca.org.uk/wp-content/plugins/assessment-quiz/quiz.swf' tried to access incompatible context 'file:///G|/Lifelong%20Learning/Active%20work/Sites/rcnhca/wp%2Dcontent/plugins/assessment%2Dquiz/as2debug.swf'
```

I have set up a crossdomain.xml file at the root of my domain like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <allow-access-from domain="*"/>
  <allow-http-request-headers-from domain="*" headers="*"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```

(seen here: http://rcnhca.org.uk/crossdomain.xml)

Strangely enough the SWF loads however when I attempt to Debug -> List variables or open it in the debugging pane it crashes the entire programme.

Comment: Perhaps you should change the title of this question? It sounds like the crossdomain.xml has addressed the sandbox violation exception, right? You might also specify which program it is you are using to debug with. Finally, I'm not sure how you can debug the code in the external SWF if you don't have the source, but maybe I never used the program you're using :)

Comment: @SunilD. No the crossdomain did nothing. I am using the Flash IDE (CS5.5). You can debug external SWFs, it semi works in AS3 but that has more problems of it's own.

Comment: Ok my bad, I didn't scroll to read the text of the exception. It seems to be saying that the SWF on the network is trying to access your debug SWF that is on your G: drive. I thought it was the other way around? Have you tried "blessing" that directory on your G: drive in Flash Player settings ("Trusted location settings")? These problems are always confusing at first, maybe I'm not helping!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're missing the code to actually load the policy file (it simply being there isn't enough):

```
Security.loadPolicyFile('your_domain/crossdomain.xml');
```

(and for any other domains you're loading from, I'd also amend your `allowDomain('*');` call to be more specific once it's all working, but it's fine for now.)

Make sure you do this at the start of your application - I've had so many headaches with this over the years, hopefully it'll be neater for you!

Hope this helps.